# Processing-Android mode error

Tags: android, processing

I am using Ubuntu 12.04,Processing 2.06b,in Android mode,
I can run code perfectly in java mode,but when running similar code in android mode,gives below error (at first time I give android sdk's path also)

```
Android SDK Tools Revision 20.0.3
Installed at /home/trendwise/android-sdk-linux
Project Type: Application

BUILD FAILED
/home/trendwise/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:517: Unable to resolve project target 'android-10'

Total time: 2 seconds
```

what does this error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately I solved this problem through extensive Google searching.

This happens when you don't have the correct **Android SDK API** installed on your machine, eg. **Android 2.3.3(API 10)**.

When you run a project/script on a device, the project is first built using the SDK, and then runs on the connected device.

To solve this, download the respective **Android SDK API** and also **Google API**.

This same problem is explained in more detail here: https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/47

Comment: Here it's explained better https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/47